# Dynamic name of cron event

Tags: actions, cron

In my multisite install, I'd like to add a daily cron event for some of the subsites. The cron will import posts via API from another website.

Because importing the content for all sites at once would end in timeout, I'd like to set a cron for each of the subsites.

In my class I did:

```
    $cron_name = 'import_blog_posts_in_network_daily_'.get_current_blog_id();
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( $cron_name) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', $cron_name );
    }
    add_action( $cron_name, array($this, 'import_blog_posts_in_network') );
```

That code registers the cron for each of my subsites correctly. But, I don't know, how can I access the name in my `import_blog_posts_in_network` callback

Is there a way to get the action name in the callback, to get the ID of my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So no, I can't see a way to grab the name of your action. However, you *can* pass arguments to your callback:

```
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
$cron_name = 'import_blog_posts_in_network_daily_'.$blog_id;
if ( !wp_next_scheduled( $cron_name) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', $cron_name, array($blog_id) );
}
add_action( $cron_name, array($this, 'import_blog_posts_in_network') );
/*
public function import_blog_posts_in_network($blog_id) {
    // do something for blog $blog_id
}
*/
```

Hope that helps!